# Unable to start Kubuntu after updating from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: boot, updates, kubuntu

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask a question about Kubuntu. Please feel free to suggest me a better place to ask this question.

I'm running dual boot windows 7 and kubuntu. Today after I run the update manager in Kubuntu to update from 13.10 to 14.04, Kubuntu doesn't boot into the desktop anymore. In the boot menu, all options now show Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu. The only way I can get to the Kubuntu desktop now is to choose the option "Ubuntu with Linux 3.15.xx (recovery mode)", then choose "enable network", and press Ctrl+C.

Please tell me how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Found the problem: the ATI graphic card driver seems to be not installed correctly. I removed the driver and Kubuntu can boot into desktop now. Still wondering why the entries in the boot menu showing Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu though.

Comment: Kubuntu is just KDE running on top of the Ubuntu system. Because of that, it will show up as Ubuntu. There's nothing to worry about with that. Also, Kubuntu is an official Ubuntu derivative, so it is completely OK to ask Kubuntu questions here.

Comment: running this command `sudo lshw | grep -A 11 *-display` will give you information about the graphics card you have add the output to your question and it will help in finding an answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Converting OP's comment into an answer)*

The ATI graphics driver wasn't installed properly. After uninstalling that, the graphical interface worked fine.